# New module in Python

Tags: python, module

I've tried to create a new module in Python. It's git link : https://github.com/Sanmitha-Sadhishkumar/strman
After uploading and installing that using pip, I found that I could access that module as

```
import strman.strman as s
s.func_name
```

What are the changes to be made to access that as

```
import strman
strman.func_name
```

Comment: You've created a module called `strman` containing a module called `strman`. If you just created one module instead, you would be able to use the second version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `__init__.py` file, you want to use a relative import.

```
from .strman import *
```

You have a `strman` package (the outer directory) and within it a `strman` module (the `strman.py` file). That's a perfectly common pattern. But without the relative import your `__init__.py` wasn't importing from deep enough in the hierarchy.

More generally, whenever you import from a sibling module within a project, you almost always should use a relative import, because it's explicit and avoids various complications, such as the example in your case.

Answer (score -1):

You have to move the files into the main directory. Your directory will look like this

```
\myProject
    - init.py
    - strman.py
    - main.py # <-- this would be the file your programming is
```

Read more about modules in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)